# Mysqli function causes database connection to fail

Tags: php, mysqli, connection

I have a function as follows:

```
function display_results() {
    $query = "SELECT *
            FROM comments WHERE id = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($result);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['comment'];
    }
}
```

In another file I include the function, and then call it:

```
<?php require_once($root . 'includes/ui_functions'); ?>
<?php display_results(); ?>
```

But it returns as "Database query failed", without any other information. This only happens since I switched from mysql_* to mysqli_* connection. The MySQL syntax is fine, it simply fails the database query no matter what I query it.

Comment: From first glance this looks like it may be a [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. Can we see how you define your `$connection`

Comment: <?php
 global $connection;
 $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
 $GLOBALS['connection'] = $connection;
?>

Comment: I should add that all other database connections work fine IF they are done on the same page that's on the screen

Comment: I think you should try using `$GLOBALS['connection']` instead of `$connection` in your `mysqli_query` call

Comment: Done, but didn't resolve the issue :(

Comment: Did you check the error logs, maybe they are more descriptive on why a connection cannot be made.

Comment: You can always try dumping whatever your connection variable is inside that function to see if it is a scoping issue

Comment: How do I check error log?

Comment: Ah yes, it was a scoping issue. When I put the mysqli_connect constants into the query it works. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I've discovered the issue

Comment: One solution would be to directly pass the connection to the function.

Comment: and you can find where your error logs are stored by viewing your php_info()